# Cast string with comma to float with dot

Tags: php, casting, floating-point

When I try to cast

```
$value = floatval('14,5833');
```

to a `float` type I expect a value with dot like `14.5833` but it returns me `14,5833`.

How should I do this ?

I wouldn't like to use any string replace functions.

Comment: *(reference)* http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

- Set locale to something that uses a dot instead of a coma. E.g. setLocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_BE.UTF-8');
- Keep using comma internally, and when you want to output that number, use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 9):

An example was helpful for me:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US');
echo 1.234; // 1.234
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'et_EE.UTF-8');
echo 1.234; // 1,234
echo number_format( 1.234, 2, '.', '' ); // 1.23 
?>
```

Comment: Note that `number_format()` will round the value. So something like 2.3456 will be formatted to 2.35 instead of 2.34

Comment: This doesn't convert to 1,234 ever for me but always 1.234 when using ubuntu 14.04 with default php `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11`

Comment: It looks like on ubuntu locales must be explicitly installed, like `$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-et-base`.

Answer (score 0):

Check `decimal_point` from [localeconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) and [setlocale](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)