# Rounding a number in PHP without converting it to the locale's representation

Tags: php, rounding

So, apparently PHP's `round()` outputs the result as a string formatted according to the current locale settings. `round( 10000.326, 1 )` might return "1.000,3", which is fine if you intend to display the result right away, but not that great if you plan to work further with it.

php.net discussion hints that there is no way to stop `round()` from localizing the output. Is there really no "pure" rounding function in the library that would return an int or a float/double so that the result could be used in arithmetical operations, or is creating your own the only option?

Comment: What is the result of the following: `print_r(localeconv());`

Comment: Maybe you could to check the official manual first: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

round() ***doesn't*** output the result as a string formatted according to the current locale settings: it returns a ***float***... and has no localization.

```
float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )
```

What you do with the result afterwards is more likely to localize it.

Where did you get the impression that round() returned a localized string?

Comment: echo, print_r or var_dump would output a string version of the float, maybe that's why he is confusing it for returning a string.

Comment: @jishi - though var_dump() should identify the value as a float

Comment: I have a function that tries to save the numbers to a database in localized form, but only if the values given to it are passed through round() first... Thanks, I'll have to check if the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't use prepared statements with typed parameters? But building SQL strings, hence, it will be outputted as a string.

Answer (score 1):

The round function returns a float but the format is localized.

```
echo round(3.14159, 2);
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
echo round(3.14159, 2);
```

This is what the original poster meant.

I suggest:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US');
```

That will set the localization for the decimal separator to English (United States) and will be a period.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too much of an expert, but perhaps `number_format()` might give you what you need? Based on the comments it doesn't appear to use locale, and I know it rounds.

Comment: number_format will take thousand separator and decimal-sign as arguments, meaning you can control the output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rounding integers:

```
floor($value + .5);
```

And add precision like this (this is one digit):

```
$digits = 1;
floor($value * pow(10, $digits) + .5) / pow(10, d$igits);
```

Answer (score 0):

use sprintf like :

```
$val = sprintf('%.1f', 1000.326);
```

gives : `1000.3`

Answer (score 0):

It's the automatic conversion to a string for output that probably causes the confusion. There's [a more direct question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996743/cast-string-with-coma-to-float-with-dot). An example was helpful for me:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US');
echo 1.234; // 1.234
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'et_EE.UTF-8');
echo 1.234; // 1,234
echo number_format( 1.234, 2, '.', '' ); // 1.23 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to force it to int you can type cast like this:

```
$rnum = (int) round( 10000.326, 1 );
```

not sure if this is what your looking for though.

you can get more info here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

this is what i did to confirm, i am not sure what your trying to achieve exactely

but this might help

```
$var = (int) "1.000,3";
$var1 = "1.000,3";

if(is_string($var)) print "true";
else print "false";

if(is_int($var)) print "true";
else print "false";

if(is_string($var1)) print "true";
else print "false";
```

the results are:

1. false
2. true
3. true

please correct me if i am wrong. thanks.

Comment: Won't work. As I said, `round( 10000.326, 1 )` returns "1.000,3" and `(int)"1.000,3"` is 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )
```

Where are you see string output???